# Worker thread immediately exits

Tags: javascript, node.js, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

I want to run a blocking task in a working thread to avoid blocking the event loop.
I got two environments, my workstation and a server. Both have the same version of NodeJS (14.16.1).

Here is a sample of my code:

```
// main.js
const workerPath = __dirname + "/worker.js";
async function doBlockingAction(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const worker = new Worker(workerPath, {workerData: data});
      worker.on("message", ({success, err}) => {
        console.log("WORKER RESPONSE");
        if (err) return reject(err);
        return resolve(success);
      });
      worker.on("exit", code => {
        console.log("WORKER EXIT", code);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
}

// worker.js
const { parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads');

try {
  // This method will block the event loop
  blockingAction(workerData);
  parentPort.postMessage({success: true, err: null});
} catch (err) {
  parentPort.postMessage({success: false, err});
}
```

On my workstation, everything works well (I get `WORKER RESPONSE` in the output). On the server, the worker immediately exits (I get `WORKER EXIT 0`)

Both files have the same permissions.

What could cause such behaviour? Why the worker thread would exit immediately?

Comment: Listen for stdout/stderr on worker, but it seems you are missing a`}` & `)` on `worker.on("exit", code => {
        console.log("WORKER EXIT", code);` You are not closing the function properly

Comment: @Marc Thank you for your response. That's a copy error, I don't have this error in my code. I will try to read stderr.

Comment: @Notiggsam did you able to find the root cause? btw me too facing similar issue.